# How To Align Shape to center of Text Photoshop Cs6

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Hello I am having problems with aligning shape to center of text. I know how to align text to center of the shape.

Every time I pick shape + text It'll align text to the shape and not shape to the text.

What should i do? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have 3 layers: text, shape and bg,
[image: Text, shape and bg layer]

and you want to center your shape relative to text. Select your shape layer and CTRL + LMOUSE on icon "T" of text layer to marquee it,
[image: Select shape layer, CTRL + LMOUSE on icon "T" of text layer to marquee it]

then simply align vertically and horizontally.
[image: align vertically and horizontally]

Comment: Hmm I don't think that what I was looking for. Here's the problem. I want to have some text (book now - for example) at the top. At the bottom I've got shape and I want to align this shape to center of the text (only shape should move to left) So there will only shape move and not the text. http://imgur.com/WR8PDVR
Thanks for help

Comment: If you only want your shape to move left, select your green shape layer, CTRL + LMOUSE on "T" icon of "BOOK NOW" layer and then simply align horizontal (http://i.imgur.com/7QK3rDl.jpg)

Comment: Glad to be of service. Have a nice day ^^

Comment: +1 for the selection method CTRL + LMOUSE. The transform tools are not active until this step is performed.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Photoshop aligns two different items to the centre of they relative width (or height). That means, that you can select both layers, align them (vertically or horizontally) and then - when they are aligned to each other - align and move both to the desire location.

[image: Center Align]